# IOS Segue is not working in Custom Tab bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, segue

i make my custom tab bar using segue it's run successfully , now i try to pass data between two  view controller which is on tab bar view controller

my code for tab bar controller

```
- (void) perform {

    ViewController *ctbcv = (ViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;
    for(UIView *view in ctbcv.placeholder.subviews)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    ctbcv.currentViewController = dst;
    [ctbcv.placeholder addSubview:dst.view];
}
```

and segue condition

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"HomeSegue"]
   || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DeveloperSegue"]
   || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DesignerSegue"]|| [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"btn4"]){

NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[self.buttons.subviews count]);

for (int i=0; i<[self.buttons.subviews count];i++) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.buttons.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        [button setSelected:NO];
    }

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)button.tag);
     btnclicked = button.tag;
    [button setSelected:YES];
}
}
```

this code run successfully, now i create button on 1st view controller and give segue to the new view controller , it's crash when click on button.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[btnnext addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{

NSLog(@"you clicked on button %ld", (long)sender.tag);

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender];

 }

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
          navVC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

  }
 }
```

After this code it crash and Xcode show "THREAD 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2 , address = 0xc)"  any solution ?

i use [this reference](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-creating-a-custom-side-tabbar-using-storyboards-and-custom-segues/) for making custom tab bar

i make button which open new view controller in this tab bar.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check out that u have put your code in the main controller that you wants to use and not in tabs of tab bar controller.